# How wget all images from website?

Tags: wget

How wget all images from site when these images aren't stored on the same domain?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to take a look at  [this link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/)

it should be something like this ;

`wget -r -A.jpg http://url-to-webpage-with-images/`

Another way that I did earlier,

1) get html source of documents

2) parse links

3) save the links in a .txt file

4) after that use `wget -i file_name.txt`

You can use [this generic class](https://github.com/arascanakin/HTMLParser) I wrote. It is easy to understand. Just look at Test.java how to use the class.

Comment: don't work, because that work only for links from this website

Comment: I thought of it before, but I don't know how parse links, there is sed regexp needed or something like it :(...

Comment: This class of mine doesn't use regex. It only uses String methods like .indexOf() and substring(). I recommend to take a look at this

Comment: so how get links to images from it?