# How wget all hotlinked images from website?

Tags: linux, wget

How wget all images from website when these images aren't stored on the same domain?

**DON'T CLOSE** same as questions 8961850, before that try download images from: tinyurl.com/7hgj7hy

Comment: Why shouldn't we close a question that's word-for-word identical to an earlier question that has been deemed off-topic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961850/how-wget-all-images-from-website

Comment: because that don't work, try it before close :<, and there is no example for it in man

Answer (score 1):

The '-r' recursive option downloads all sublinks on a page, and '-H' makes it regardless of their domain.

```
wget -rH http://something.com
```

Comment: Filtering which files you want to download is a different issue than the part I answered; -H successfully removes the domain limitation you mentioned in the question.